# How to clean a matrix from non sense entries?

Tags: r

Good afternoon,

Suppose that my R code generates the following result ( a variable called `res` ) :

```
       row col      value
X3       3   2 0.29430355
X13.4   13  22 0.19449339
X15.12  15  23 0.14153697
X223    22  10 0.10826823
X17.23  17   6 0.08550234
X195    19  11 0.06907010
61       6  16 0.04728460
X36      3  16 0.03982965
X227    22   1 0.03386338
```

How can I delete the column at the left where we have ( X3 , X13.4 , etc )?

Thank you a lot for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the rownames to `NULL`

```
row.names(res) <- NULL
```